# Symlinks in Centos

Tags: php, apache, centos

i have dirs:

```
/var/www/site1/images/*.jpg
```

And

```
/var/www/site2/
```

So, I want symlink images from site1 to site2. 
I run:

```
ln /var/www/site1/images /var/www/site2
```

Is ok. If I check function :
`file_exist(site2/images/example.jpg)` that ok but if I want:

```
<img src="site2/images/examples.jpg" />
```

Result: 403 Forbidden

Comment: This isn't really a PHP question. But check here for an answer: http://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks

Answer (score 1):

You are making a hard link for a folder, this doesn't work.
Try with "-s" option, this will make a symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

Hard links to directories are not permitted by most filesystems, so you’ll probably have
to create a symbolic link.

The ln command creates hard links by default. To create a
symbolic link, pass the -s or --symbolic option to the command.

```
ln -s /source /link
```